# AWS CLI tools on Circle CI: configure: unknown command

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04, aws-cli, circleci

I'm trying to deploy a docker application onto Elastic Beanstalk from Circle CI.

The deployment section of my circle.yml is

```
deployment:
  hub:
    branch: [internal, production]
    commands:
      - pip install awscli
      - docker push company/web:$CIRCLE_SHA1
      - sudo bash deploy.sh $CIRCLE_SHA1 $CIRCLE_BRANCH $CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM
```

and my deploy.sh calls aws cli as follows

```
aws --version
aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWSKEY
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWSSECRETKEY
aws configure set default.region us-west-2
aws configure set default.output json

echo "SAVING NEW DOCKERRUNFILE: $DOCKERRUN_FILE"
aws s3 cp $DOCKERRUN_FILE s3://$EB_BUCKET/$DOCKERRUN_FILE
```

But I get the error

> --version: mispelled meta parameter?
>
> sanity-check: "/root/.awssecret": file is missing.  (Format: AccessKeyID\nSecretAccessKey\n)
>
> configure: unknown command Usage: aws ACTION [--help]

The script works completely fine locally on mac os using the exact same key and secret.

Both versions (on circle and my mac) of awscli are 1.7.14

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm Kevin from CircleCI. It looks like the issue here is related to the fact that when you install Python dependencies CircleCI installs them into a virtualenv. This is usually a great thing, as it isolates your python environment from the default system Python and supports our dependency cacheing. The problem here is that you're running your `deploy.sh` script with sudo, which clobbers the virtualenv environment and runs the default system version (which in this case is actually an older alternative AWS CLI). Dropping the sudo should fix things for you. (You would also be better off running `pip install awscli==x.x.x` in the "dependencies" phase, as it would be cached then.)

PS: Please contact sayhi@circleci.com for a timely response to questions in general.